# Getting loop data aligned properly in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, html-table, alignment

I'm practicing right now.  I understand how to do the loops, but I can't get the data aligned properly

```
<html lang = "en">

    <head>
        <title>Javascript practice</title>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href = "css/foundation.min.css"></link>

        <style type = "text/css">
         table         { width: 300px;
                         border-collapse:collapse; 
                         background-color: lightblue; }
         table, td, th { border: 1px solid black; 
                         padding: 4px; }
         th            { text-align: left; 
                         color: white;
                         background-color: darkblue; }
         tr.oddrow     { background-color: white; }
      </style>
    </head>


    <body>



        <! -- JavaScript -->
        <script type = "text/javascript">

            var ALEast   =  ["Yankees", "Red Sox", "Orioles", "Rays", "Blue-Jays"];


            var count = 1;

            document.write('<table border = "3">');


            document.write('<thead style = "height:100px;"><tr><th>N</th><th>10*N</th><th>100*N</th><th>1000*N</th></thead>');








            for(var i = 0; i < ALEast.length; i++)
                {

                    document.write('<tr><td>' + ALEast[i] + '</td></tr>');

                }   

            for(var count = 1; count <= 6; count++)
                {
                    document.write('<tr><tr><td><td>' + count + '</tr><</td></td>');
                }


        document.write('</table>');



        </script>
        <!-- End JavaScript -->


    </body>
</html>
```

I want my count loop, numbers 1 through 6 to go directly underneath my 10*N header.  But I can't get it there.  If you run my code, you'll see it's in the second column, but too low, and not directly to the right of "Yankees".

So basically I want the number 1 to be directly to the right of Yankees, and 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 listed underneath.

Comment: You have one column in the first loop and no colspan. One `tr` element is one row. So it must have as many td elements in it as you have as your heading (th). And you can't have tr inside of another tr (in loop number two). Sort out the html part and js will be a lot easier.

Comment: there are some things wrong in your code (not sure if they are just missing by typo). As I understand you need to print a table of 2 columns?

Comment: Right now I just want my count loop, which prints out numbers 1 through 6, to appear under the second column, "10*N".  As it stands right now, my Count loop is appearing underneath the baseball teams in the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not JavaScript, but your understanding of `table, tr, and td`. You also have a double `<<` that has no sense. In general, you need to know how HTML works.

· `table` is just a mark to start a table.
· `tr` is to create a new row.
· `td` is not create a new column. (The same as `th`)

Important! Note that each opening tag has to have a closing tag with `/`, for example `<tr><td></td></tr>`, and has to be closed in the inverted order, so closing them this way `<tr><td></tr></td>` is an error.

So, looking at your code, your table will be made this way (considering that `ALEast` has a length of 3, for example):

```
Line #01: <table>
Line #02: <thead style = "height:100px;"><tr><th>N</th><th>10*N</th><th>100*N</th><th>1000*N</th></thead>
Line #03: <tr><td>' + ALEast[0] + '</td></tr>
Line #04: <tr><td>' + ALEast[1] + '</td></tr>
Line #05: <tr><td>' + ALEast[2] + '</td></tr>
Line #06: <tr><tr><td><td>1</tr><</td></td>
Line #07: <tr><tr><td><td>2</tr><</td></td>
Line #08: <tr><tr><td><td>3</tr><</td></td>
Line #09: <tr><tr><td><td>4</tr><</td></td>
Line #10: <tr><tr><td><td>5</tr><</td></td>
Line #11: <tr><tr><td><td>6</tr><</td></td>
Line #12: </table>
```

I'll explain what you have a bit:

- In the line #01 you are creating the table, everything fine with this.
- In the line #02 you are creating the header. As you see you have created a new row (`tr`) and created a new colum for each header with (`th`). Everything is fine with this too.
- Now in the lines from #03 to number #05 (The first loop), for each item you are just creating a new row with `tr` and each row will only have 1 colum (only one `td`)
- And the second loop (from line #06 to line #11), each time you are creating 2 rows (2 `tr`). Note that the first `tr` don't have the closing tag `/tr` so the second row is created inside the first row (rowception), this is an error. Also the same with the next, you are creating 2 colums with 2 `td` and the second column is created inside the first colum because it don't has the closing tag `/td`. After that you put the count and close the row (?) with `/tr`, then you put a double `<<` (? again) and close 2 columns with `/td`.
- After all this aberration, you end your table with `</table>`in the line #12.

So, in general, when you design/program you must understand what you are doing. For this you need an high dose of HTML coding tutorials. Start here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: Thanks. I'd upvote you if I could, but I don't have enough rep.  This is just practice for an assignment, so I can't manually put in numbers 1 through 6 in the second column, i need to iterate them via for loops.  The baseball stuff is random and unrelated to the assignment, but I will need to do calculations in each columns.  I believe the first column will have 1 through 6, via iteration, the second 10 through 60, via iteration, the third column 100 through 600, via iteration (for loops).  Is that possible with the logic we have above?

Comment: @user3577397 So, you want the first column to have 6 rows, from number 1 to number 6, the second colum 51 rowns, from number 10 to number 60, and etc...?

Comment: No.  I actually figured it out.  The assignment called for me to have N column = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;  Next column over = 10 *N = 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60;  Next column over = 100 * N = 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600; Next column over = 1000 * N = 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000;    And we were supposed to fill this table in via a For Loop.   I was able to do it with everyone's help in here.  The Loops weren't tough, it was organizing it in the table.

Comment: @user3577397 Ah that's fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have some erros in your code, some missing closing tags too, so I've checked your code then fixed errors.

```
<head>
    <title>Javascript practice</title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href = "css/foundation.min.css"></link>

    <style type = "text/css">
     table         { width: 300px;
                     border-collapse:collapse; 
                     background-color: lightblue; }
     table, td, th { border: 1px solid black; 
                     padding: 4px; }
     th            { text-align: left; 
                     color: white;
                     background-color: darkblue; }
     tr.oddrow     { background-color: white; }
  </style>
</head>


<body>



    <! -- JavaScript -->
    <script type = "text/javascript">

        var ALEast   =  ["Yankees", "Red Sox", "Orioles", "Rays", "Blue-Jays"];


        var count = 1;

        document.write('<table border = "3">');


        document.write('<thead style = "height:100px;"><tr><th>N</th><th>10*N</th><th>100*N</th><th>1000*N</th></tr></thead>');




        for(var i = 0; i < ALEast.length; i++)
            {

                document.write('<tr><td>' + ALEast[i] + '</td><td>'+ i +'</td></tr>');

            }   


    document.write('</table>');



    </script>
    <!-- End JavaScript -->


</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I ran your fixes and I still can't get my count loop to appear in the second column under "10*N"  Not sure how to get it there.

Comment: Thanks you.  I figured out how to put my iterations in the table.